# How do I combine functions in Google Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm pretty code illiterate, so I took other peoples stuff and tried smashing it together so it might look stupid, just laying all my cards out.

I tried running all the scripts individually, but I saw that you can't do that in a different post on this site. Tried combining them, played with it a few hours but didn't achieve jack.

```
  myFunction1();
  myFunction2();
  myFunction3();
  myFunction4();
SHEET_NAME = "Top5k";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A2:B999";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 1, ascending: false},
];

function myFunction1(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}

SHEET_NAME = "TopR1";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A2:B999";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 1, ascending: false},
];

function myFunction2(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort one complete.');
}

SHEET_NAME = "TopR2";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A2:B999";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 1, ascending: false},
];

function myFunction3(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}

SHEET_NAME = "TopR3";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A2:B999";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 1, ascending: false},
];

function myFunction4(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
}
```

When I run the script as is, it has no errors and nothing happens on edit except the ss.toast popup. The script should've sorted all the data across the 4 sheets every time an edit event was registered had I not jacked something up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon what I can see in your script this should be able to do it for you.

```
function sortingStuff() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheetByName('Top5K').getRange('A2:B999').sort({column:1,ascending:false});
  ss.getSheetByName('TopR1').getRange('A2:B999').sort({column:1,ascending:false});
  ss.getSheetByName('TopR2').getRange('A2:B999').sort({column:1,ascending:false});
  ss.getSheetByName('TopR3').getRange('A2:B999').sort({column:1,ascending:false});
  ss.toast('Sorting Complete');
}
```